# Animation css does not work

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have to move image in sliding dynamically. But it does not work.
Here my css and html code.

```css
.demo-section{
  background: url('http://xxxxx/images/homepages/faces.png') repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  -webkit-animation: sliding 60s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: sliding 60s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: sliding 60s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: sliding 60s linear infinite;
  animation: sliding 60s linear infinite;
  padding: 55px 0 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo-section">
  <h1>Demo Content</h1> 
</div>
```

Comment: Did you actually [define your animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)? If so, it'd be a good idea to post that code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will solve u r problem, Try this:

```
.demo-section{
  background: url('http://xxxxx/images/homepages/faces.png') no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    -webkit-transition: left 3s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: left 3s;
    left:10px;
    position:relative;
    padding: 55px 0 45px;
}

div:hover {
    left: 100px;
}
```

Thanks.